# Opencart ajax post query to database not working

Tags: php, ajax, opencart

I am testing opencart in XAMPP. I added this [extension](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9637) which checks zip code and enables to give zip code based shipping. Demo is [here](http://ecommerce.aleaitsolutions.in/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=40). It may not be compatible with the latest version.

The code was not working initially and after some modifications the admin side works. I can insert/modify zip code, etc., which means there is no issues in database.

In the catalog side however I am helpless. There is this ajax button which is not working.

```
<div class="pincode">
        <span><strong>Enter pincode to check serviceability:</strong></span><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="zip_code" value="" id="zip_code" size="8">
        <a id="button_zipcode" class="button" title="Check"><span>Check</span></a><br><br>
        <div id="temp_zipcode" style="width:94%;"></div>
```

which gets enabled with this script

```
    $('#button_zipcode').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/zipcode',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'zip_code='+$('#zip_code').val(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();


            if (json['warning']) {
                $('#temp_zipcode').html('<div class="warning" style="display: none;">' + json['warning'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');
                $('.warning').fadeIn('slow');
            }

            if (json['success']) {
                $('#temp_zipcode').html('<div class="success" style="display: none;">' + json['success'] + '<img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png" alt="" class="close" /></div>');                  
                $('.success').fadeIn('slow');
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

`url: 'index.php?route=product/product/zipcode',` what this means? if it is controller/product/product.php what should I add to make it work? The code should check zip code with DB and give output.

And there is another page as catalog/model/localisation/zip_code.php which has

```
    <?php
class ModelLocalisationZipCode extends Model {
    public function getZipCode($zip_code_id) {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zip_code WHERE zip_code_id = '" . (int)$zip_code_id . "' AND status = '1'");

        return $query->row;
    }       

    public function getCodeByZip($zip_code) {
        $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zip_code WHERE zip_code LIKE '" . $zip_code . "' AND status = '1'");     
        return $query1;
    }
}
?>
```

Is there anyway to make it work?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: It doesn work at all??...and, wht happens if you put the path manually?

Comment: no... if I click it stays mum... no effect... do you mean this path catalog/model/localisation/zip_code.php, can I add it the same way?

Comment: Yes you can add the path manually just for testing purpose....to see if it reach the file via ajax or not

Comment: I think by path you mean model/localisation/zip_code.php, I added it but it did not work

Comment: if you put that path(yes that path xD) in the nav bar....it shows something?

Comment: what do you see in your firebug?

Comment: okay... I put http://localhost/opencart/catalog/model/localisation/zip_code.php in nav bar and got Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart\catalog\model\localisation\zip_code.php on line 2

Comment: you should not access the model directly from address bar. only controllers

Comment: is it like firebug shows some err messages?

Comment: you can start debugging on firebug. see the ajax response or error in the console. the `url: 'index.php?route=product/product/zipcode'` is controller/product/product.php zipcode function

Comment: oh ok, it shows "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=product/product/zipcode" 
and if it means controller/product/product.php there is no mention of zip_code besides $this->data['button_zip'] = $this->language->get('button_zip');

Comment: have you checked the product.php controller?

Comment: do you mean controller/product/product.php, if yes there is no mentioning of anything besides $this->data['button_zip'] = $this->language->get('button_zip');

Comment: ah. you installed new extension right? are you using vqmod? or directly overwritten the files? what are the files in the new extension installed? i think there is something wrong in your installation

Comment: the extension only adds new files, there is no overwriting any stuff and this is not vqmod... the installation is all right as I am checking first in local XAMPP and again in live website... the extension needs adding a table in database and in admin side, we can add new zip codes, up to this part I managed to get everything. I believe I need to add a public function code to catalog/controller/product/product.php, this should check db if zip code is available which is where I am helpless...

Comment: aha. i downloaded the extension. You did not read the file_changes.txt hehe read it and you'll see

Comment: hey, is it working now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `catalog/controller/product/product.php`

add the fallowing code :

```
public function zipcode() {
$this->language->load('product/zipcode');

$this->load->model('localisation/zip_code');

$json = array();

if (isset($this->request->post['zip_code'])) {
    $zip_code = $this->request->post['zip_code'];
} else {
    $zip_code = 0;
}

$zone_data = $this->model_localisation_zip_code->getCodeByZip($zip_code);

if($zone_data->num_rows == 0)
{
    $json['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_warning'));
}
else
{
    $city_name = $zone_data->row['city_name'];
    $state_name = $zone_data->row['state_name'];
    $zone_name = $zone_data->row['zone_name'];    

    $json['success'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_success'),     $city_name, $state_name, $zone_name);
}

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));     
}
```

Comment: the only one file I did not read... and I wasted like three days... lol... thank you so much...

Comment: am new here, how to do that?